# Forwarding to GitLab Subdomain with Existing Nginx Installation

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, reverse-proxy, gitlab

I've been following the [instructions from the GitLab wiki](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/settings/nginx.md#using-a-non-bundled-web-server), however, it seems as if some key pieces of information are missing. In the section "Using a Non-Bundled Web Server" it never explains how I need to reconfigure my Nginx installation to reverse proxy over to GitLab.

Basically, I'd like to have GitLab installed under git.example.com, but I can't seem to find the configuration settings for my existing Nginx installation that'll do that. The wiki page goes on to talk about configuring an existing Passenger/Nginx installation, but I don't have Passenger, so I don't think that applies to my situation.

I suppose the easiest solution would be if there were a way to tell Gitlab to use it's built-in Nginx and just listen on an internal port, and then have my other Nginx forward to that port, but I can't seem to figure out how to configure Gitlab to handle that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on @cyberchis's answer i simplified the process, and I have got through the same setup twice. I hope that it also works for you.

1. **Check the user of nginx**

   1.1. Open *nginx.conf* with `nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.

   1.2. Check the 1st. line `user www-data;`, and the user here is `www-data`.
2. **Edit external_url of gitlab**

   2.1. Open *gitlab.rb* with `nano /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`.

   2.2. Edit the line `external_url 'GENERATED_EXTERNAL_URL'`  to `external_url 'http://gitlab.yourdomain.com'`.

   2.3. Uncomment and change the line `nginx['enable'] = true` to `nginx['enable'] = false`.

   2.4. Uncomment and change the line `web_server['external_users'] = []` to `web_server['external_users'] = ['www-data']`.
3. **Add a configuration file for gitlab**

   3.1. Download the *gitlab-omnibus-nginx.conf* from [gitlab repository](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-recipes/tree/master/web-server/nginx).

   3.2. Go to the directory where the file is, and copy this file to nginx with `cp /directory-to-this-file/gitlab-omnibus-nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled`.

   3.3. Open this file with `nano /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/gitlab-omnibus-nginx.conf`.

   3.4. Change this line `listen 0.0.0.0:80 default_server;` to `listen 0.0.0.0:7001;` // gitlab runs on port 7001

   3.5. Change this line `listen [::]:80 default_server;` to `listen [::]:7001;` // gitlab runs on port 7001

   3.6. Change this line `server_name YOURSERVER_FQDN` to `server_name www.yourdomain.com`.
4. **Configure nginx**

   4.1. Open *nginx.conf* with `nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.

   4.2. Add this configuration

```
http {

   ...
  
   server {
       listen 80;
       server_name gitlab.yourdomain.com;
       location / {
           proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7001;
       }
   }
}
```

5. **Reconfigure gitlab and reload nginx**

   5.1. `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure`

   5.2. `sudo systemctl reload nginx`
6. **Configure firewall to export port 7001** (*Optional*)

   Since the gitlab runs on my local server, therefore the port 7001 has to been allowed to reach from the outside. Easiest way to enable it is to run `ufw allow 7001`.

Now the gitlab runs on your subdomain *gitlab.yourdomain.com* which you should access.

Comment: if you can help, seems that piplines don't work when i use external nginx...

Answer (score 12):

I got it working! So insanely excited!

So as I said, I was attempting to follow [these instructions](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/settings/nginx.md#using-a-non-bundled-web-server), but I wasn't getting anywhere, since it seemed to be lacking instructions on how to make your existing Nginx install link into Gitlab.

Well, further down on the page they have a more complete explanation for [Using an Existing Passenger / Nginx Installation](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/settings/nginx.md#using-an-existing-passenger-nginx-installation), and while at first that didn't seem like what I wanted, researching Passenger a bit made it clear that it wasn't a Ruby-only thing(their easily-found install instructions require you to install it as a ruby gem) and their [instructions for Ubuntu installation](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#install_on_debian_ubuntu) allowed me to integrate it into my existing Nginx reasonably easily.

From there, it was just follow the steps in the wiki, although with a couple changes.

1. The [Existing Passenger/Nginx Installation](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/settings/nginx.md#using-an-existing-passenger-nginx-installation) section fails to mention what the previous section on [non-bundled Nginx install](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/settings/nginx.md#using-a-non-bundled-web-server) says, that you need to add `www-data` to the `web_server['external_users']` line in the `gitlab.rb` file.
2. Since I reconfigured my Gitlab installation to remove the bundled Nginx before I ran it the first time, the nginx log file at `/var/log/gitlab/nginx/gitlab_access.log` was non-existent, and this caused an error when Nginx tried to start up, simply creating that blank file and giving it proper read/write access made it work like a charm.

I'm super psyched now, hope anyone who has as specific of a problem in the future comes across this, that Wiki should really be updated to simply remove/merge those two sections and explain/link to how to install Passenger into an existing Nginx installation. Would have saved me a lot of confusion and wasted time.

Answer (score 8):

Run with existing Nginx server on Ubuntu

1. Install gitlab
2. Edit configuration file /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb and uncomment or append following:

   - nginx['enable'] = false
   - unicorn['enable'] = false
   - gitlab_rails['internal_api_url'] = 'http://git.yourdomain.com'
   - web_server['external_users'] = ['www-data']
3. Start bundled postgres database server

   - sudo gitlab-ctl start postgresql
4. Reconfigure

   - sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
5. Add nginx configuration file for git lab to /etc/nginx/sites-available/gitlab-example.conf and enable it via sites-enabled

   - https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/settings/nginx.md#using-a-non-bundled-web-server
6. Enable passenger for nginx

   - https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/nginx/install/oss/trusty
7. Restart nginx

   - sudo service nginx restart
8. Start redis

   - sudo gitlab-ctl start redis

Comment: These instructions helped me a bit more than the accepted answer by Eckster but I'm a little confused about the Phusion Passenger step. What does Passenger do here? I actually didn't install it and it _seems_ to be working as expected?

Comment: Good point, I made the mistake of linking to a wiki instead of just explaining all the steps, I've changed the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

It took me a couple of days to get everything sorted out, so I wanted to share the steps it took to get it all working. This is how to install Nginx for a website and get it working with an existing gitlab repo (that uses a bundled version of Nginx). MY gitlab repo is on a subdomain of my website called 'repos'.

**Open a terminal and install Nginx:**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nginx
```

**Edit configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:**

Find your user name, which you will need when configuring gitlab:
In my case this was 'nginx':

```
user   nginx;
```

Add this line inside the http{ }  block :

```
$include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

Example:

```
http{
    include  etc/nginx/mime.types;
    include  etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

    (more stuff...)
}
```

**Edit configuration file /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb:**

Change this line:

```
external_url 'GENERATED_EXTERNAL_URL'
```

To:

```
external_url 'http://www.example.com/repos'  // (whatever your server name is)
```

Uncomment and change this line:

```
nginx['enable'] = true
```

To:

```
nginx['enable'] = false
```

Uncomment and change this line:

```
web_server['external_users'] = []
```

To:

```
web_server['external_users'] = ['nginx']     // or whatever your nginx user is called, sometimes it's 'www-data'
```

**Nginx needs a configuration file for gitlab:**

On the GitLab recipes repository: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-recipes/tree/master/web-server/nginx find 'gitlab-omnibus-nginx.conf'. 
Put that file in the folder /etc/nginx/sites-enabled   (you may need to create the sites-enabled folder)

**Edit configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/gitlab-omnibus-nginx.conf:**

Change this line:

```
server_name YOUR_SERVER_FQDN
```

To:

```
server_name www.example.com/repos     // (or whatever your server name is)
```

You will need to change the port that gitlab is on so that the website and git server both work.

Change this line:

```
listen 0.0.0.0:80 default_server;
```

To:

```
listen 0.0.0.0:8081;
```

Change this line:

```
listen [::]:80  default_server;
```

To:

```
listen [::]:8081;
```

**Edit configuration file /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:**

Make this the default server:

```
listen    80 default_server;
server_name  localhost;
```

Add a second location for the gitlab repo and use proxy_pass to point to the port you put Gitlab on.
I put my Gitlab in the sub-directory 'repos'. The number 127.0.0.1 means localhost (the same computer):

```
location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
}
location /repos/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
}
```

**Run these commands in the terminal:**

```
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
sudo service nginx restart
```

Your webserver and gitlab should now both be working and accessible online.
Nginx will default to /usr/share/nginx/html when a user visits your webserver. There is a default .html file there. That is where you can put files for your website.

Comment: So you are running your Gitlab without HTTPS?

Answer (score 1):

The post of @fillky couldn't fully help me for my ubuntu 18.04 installation. These are my steps with which I've got Gitlab to work.

For **Ubuntu 18.04** (http mode):

1. Install Gitlab (step 1 & 2 from https://about.gitlab.com/install/#ubuntu)
2. Edit configuration file /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb and uncomment or append following (found here https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#configuration):

   nginx['enable'] = false

   unicorn['enable'] = false

   gitlab_rails['internal_api_url'] = 'http://gitlab.yourdomain.com'

   web_server['external_users'] = ['www-data']
3. Reconfigure Gitlab

   sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
4. Enable passenger for nginx (steps 1 to 3 from https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/nginx/install/oss/bionic/)
5. Reload nginx to check if everything still works. If not: google is your friend

   sudo nginx -s reload
6. Change your nginx configuration to support gitlab. Create a 'gitlab' file in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled with the contents from the Vhost step of the original documentation:

   https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#vhost-server-block
7. Reload nginx, so the changes take effect

   sudo nginx -s reload
8. Install node.js (if not yet installed) as gitlab needs JavaScript execution

   sudo apt-get install node.js
9. Browse to your gitlab url. You should be prompted for a password for your root gitlab account. In the next step you'll be able to login with that account

That's all! If you want HTTPS enabled, do the following extra steps:

1. Change the 'external_url' in /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb from http to https
2. Change the nginx config /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/gitlab to use ssl

   listen 0.0.0.0:443 ssl;
   listen [::]:443 ipv6only=on ssl;
   ssl on;
   ssl_certificate #link to your public ssl certificate
   ssl_certificate_key #link to your private ssl key
   ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4";
   ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
   ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
   ssl_session_timeout 5m;
3. Reconfigure gitlab

   sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
4. Reload nginx

   sudo nginx -s reload

Answer (score 0):

For those people for whom the listed answers did not work. My own answer was to edit `nginx.conf` and uncomment the `include /etc/nginx/passenger.conf;` line.

Its absense prevented nginx from doing anything with passenger.