# Get error 500 in gitlab's CI process

Tags: nginx, gitlab

I installed gitlab with my own Nginx(I disabled the build-in nginx), Everything works fine before I tried to use CI in it.

After I commit the pipeline started, and give the message:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 10.1.0 (c1ecf97f)
on the runner for wxEditor (fccd792d)
Using Docker executor with image node:8.8.1 ...
Using docker image 
sha256:c3a98397674933da01d4fc1e90dc880b1fb0760fedc43515e7660dcc58c6af28 for 
predefined container...
Pulling docker image node:8.8.1 ...
Using docker image node:8.8.1 
ID=sha256:d575940ea42b064ac3fa5b00c36ec099968ce2ae542488d1d8673f100dc0a622 for 
build container...
Running on runner-fccd792d-project-2-concurrent-0 via vps143760...
Cloning repository...
Cloning into '/builds/zhaozhong/wxEditor'...
fatal: unable to access 'http://gitlab-ci-
token:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@gitlab.dingshao.cc/zhaozhong/wxEditor.git/': The 
requested URL returned error: 500
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

I've got stucked here for a hole day.

Gitlab EE: 10.1.0, ubuntu 16.04

Thanks

Comment: Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

I ran gitlab with my excisting nginx and use an old nginx config file, and there should be nginx + passenger which insure gitlab to get to work.

After read [this anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29403212/forwarding-to-gitlab-subdomain-with-existing-nginx-installation), I reinstalled Nginx together with passenger, and copy the bundled Nginx's config file gitlab-http.conf to the Nginx's sites-enable folder, every works perfect then.